# How to use Malloc Debug for checking native memory leaks?

Tags: android, c++, c, memory-leaks

I am exploring several options to figure out the best tool/way to find out memory leaks in native code in android app. As part of this exercise, I came across the option present in following url.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/malloc_debug/README_marshmallow_and_earlier.md

I wrote a sample app which calls a native function written in shared library. I put memory leak intentionally in this native function. Before running the app, I did

1. adb shell setprop libc.debug.malloc.program
2. adb shell setprop libc.debug.malloc 10

Then I started the app. But I could not see any prints in the logcat indicating memory leak.

If anybody has ever used this approach to find out the native memory leaks, could you please tell me if I am missing some thing. Is the logcat logs correct place to look for the leak messages? If not, how should I find the leak information?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  You should be using `new` instead of `malloc` in C++, because `malloc` does not call the object's constructor method.

Comment: You may want to consider not using dynamic memory allocation in an embedded system.  Memory allocation may lead to unrecoverable fragmentation or memory leaks.  Search the internet for "C++ memory pool" and "C++ placement new".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews android, although an embedded system in a technical sense, is certainly not constrained in terms of memory, and memory allocation there is fine. It also should not lead to memory leaks, unless used improperly.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to set backtrace based on the version your application has.

Try this command:

```
adb shell setprop libc.debug.malloc.options backtrace
```

Then take dumpheap.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/malloc_debug/README.md    please try this